# Unable to connect to establish a socket connection using QTcpSocket to a linux box (telnet works)

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qtcpsocket

code:

```
watchTowerSocket = new QTcpSocket();
watchTowerSocket->connectToHost("198.168.101.230", 4400);

if(watchTowerSocket->waitForConnected())
{
    qDebug() << "Connected";
    watchTowerSocket->write("HELLO SERVER");
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Not Connected";
}
```

When I run my application, I get "Connected" on the console. However, my server (which is running on a linux box) does not receive a connection. Also, I ran wireshark and found that no TCP packet is getting generated when the above code is being run. 
What must I try to fix this?

Comment: Where is the server and client running from? two different machines? When you ping the server you see packets being sent on wireshark?

Comment: @Griffin They are two distinct machines. I am able to ping that machine, when I run telnet, I am able to connect. My concern is the waitForConnected() function returning true. I didn't expect that if it is unable to connect.

Comment: And what does `write()` return? Also what happens if you change the IP to something invalid? Smells like this is not the code compiled.

Comment: You don't even check for states, errors ... anything. Just take a look at Examples for QTcpSocket. There is a lot of them. Here is one for blocking communication using QTcpSockets -> http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-example.html Works out of the box